# How to render site as if it were on an iPhone?

Tags: html, mobile, web

I am trying to debug a display issue with a site, but I am only able to reproduce the bug when viewing the site on an iPhone.  I tried changing the user agent in Safari to iPhone, but the bug is not reproduced when viewing on Safari emulating an iPhone.

Shouldn't these two render the same?  Am I missing something?

At the end of the day I would just like to reproduce the bug and then use developer tools to see what is causing it.  Is there a reliable way to render a site as if it were on a mobile device while in a desktop environment so that one can use developer tools?

Comment: Xcode developer tools has an iOS simulator which you can use? If you're on a mac.. You can then open safari and set safaris debugging tools to look at the simulator, that's how I usually deal with iphone/ipad bugs..

Comment: Ohh that's awesome, I didn't know you could do that.  If you post as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Added, glad to share the knowledge, it's saved me many headaches!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a Mac you can use Xcode to debug iPhone or iPad using a combination of iOS simulator and Safari.

Open iOS simulator as usual, now in Safari (on your Mac, not in the simulator) under the develop menu you can choose to point the debugging tools at the iOS simulated screen.

[image: Screenshot of developer menu in Safari when iOS simulator is open]

You can then debug with the Safari debugging tools.

Answer (score 1):

User agent alone isn't likely to make a lot of difference to the rendering of the site. Is Safari a requirement? Chrome includes a tool for emulating screen size and user agent, so if the rending issue is due to layout constraints this might help you reproduce it.

[image: Device Emulation]